# Roslyn - how detect code files that are auto-generated?

Tags: roslyn, roslyn-code-analysis

Is it possible to detect if `Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Document` has been auto-generated by a tool?

For example:

```cs
foreach(var document in project.Documents)
{
    if (!document.IsGeneratedCode())
    {
        // TODO
    }

}
```

Looking at the [source code on GitHub](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/blob/b5edce4772b791624884bbfa6ba3c5e60addd757/src/Workspaces/SharedUtilitiesAndExtensions/Workspace/Core/Extensions/DocumentExtensions.cs), I found out that extension methods `IsGeneratedCode` and `IsGeneratedCodeAsync` exist, but only as **internal** helpers. Implementation calls `IGeneratedCodeRecognitionService` language service that is also **internal**.

Is there any way to use similar functionality in external console application?

Answer (score 1):

Not ideal, but you could copy the [internal logic](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/blob/cf55f3a58e47298426fa971d3bd9d8857c746c65/src/Compilers/Core/Portable/InternalUtilities/GeneratedCodeUtilities.cs). Basically, code is considered "generated" if:

- File begins with auto-generated comment `// <autogenerated />`
- File name starts with `TemporaryGeneratedFile_`
- File name ends with `.designer`, `.generated`, `.g`, or `.g.i` right before the extension

Comment: I did that eventually, but problem with copying is that I can end up running different implementation, if Roslyn team updates/improves their code. Ideally, this functionality should be exposed  publicly somewhere.